# Running PHP and MySQL with XAMPP in Ubuntu (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, xampp

I'm quite new to Linux and still trying to adapt my self. I've setup my working environment all good, installed XAMPP, node, sublime, etc. But when I tried running a laravel app, the first thing that caught me was I couldn't run php.

I was confused because i had already installed XAMPP (which i thought would've done it all for me), but then I simply created a symlink in my /usr/bin to the /opt/lampp/bin/php and it all worked well (I'm not sure if that was all correct, but it worked).

Then when I tried opening the app in my browser, it couldn't find the sql driver, so I asked my self, what exactly am I doing wrong? XAMPP should have taken care of all those things (as its name suggests), but it didn't setup php and mysql as i thought it would.

Am I missing something here? Should I install MySQL driver and PHP apart from XAMPP? Because that makes no sense at all for me. I really need some basic guidance here about this whole thing, what makes it so different from Windows where I simply install XAMPP and start programming?

I need to understand that so I can have a better understanding of the system it self and fix these kind of problems my self in the future.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and instaled XAMPP with PHP 7.0, downloaded from official website.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why are you using XAMPP? You can just install PHP and MySQL via apt-get, if it's not already installed.

Comment: Extending what @aynber correctly remarked you should install _all_ components you need on a system via the distributions software management system. So here MySQL, PHP, Apache and all dependencies. That is _exactly_ what software management systems are great in. if it easier, more secure and more reliable. If you perform wild installations into the file system, bypassing the software management, then no one takes care of dependencies, updates, upgrades and especially removals.

Comment: @arkascha and aynber, that's exactly what I needed to know. So I should avoid these kind of packs and install one by one. The problem now is I'll have to learn how to install everything I need, because I don't even know what I need since I always just installed XAMPP and started programming hehe, but that's something I'm gonna dig in now. Tanks a lot guys, it really helped me understand what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

I never used xampp on linux myself so i dont know how does it work here but I can tell you what really got me good start at understanding of linux  was installing whole LAMP stack myself. So i would recommend googling 'How To Install LAMP' and try to figure it out from countless tutorials.

Basically you install apache, then mysql and php, restart server and check if 'It works'.

Answer (score 0):

try two things

In the folder `/etc/php/php.ini`

uncheck the line `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

or in the folder of `lampp` (`/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`)

And to start Laravel you need start with `~/php` artisan serve

in the browser `localhost:8000`